# C# dictionary with list as value, can I directly operate on the list?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a doubt regarding dictionary and list, I create a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<int, List<int>> mainGraph = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
```

Then I want to extend the list of an existing key, and doing it in this way no problem:

```
public void addLinkToGraph(int oldKey,int newValue)
{
    List<int> dummyList = mainGraph[oldKey];
    dummyList .Add(newValue);
    mainGraph[oldKey] = dummyList;
}
```

But if I try to do it directly on the dictionary list:

```
public void addLinkToGraph(int oldKey,int newValue)
{
    mainGraph[oldKey] = mainGraph[oldKey].Add(newValue);
}
```

It return error:

> Error  CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Can someone help me understand why and if anyway firs solution is a good way to do this?

Comment: `.Add(newValue)` does not return a value, it is `void`.

Comment: `mainGraph[oldKey].Add(newValue);` should do the trick.

Comment: In your first snippet, `mainGraph[oldKey] = dummyList` is unnecessary - there is no need to re-assign the same list to the key in the dictionary because List.Add() adds to the existing object rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply do it directly on the list without returning anything:

```
public void addLinkToGraph(int oldKey,int newValue)
{
    mainGraph[oldKey].Add(newValue);
}
```

Comment: Tks It was really simple, I should've tought about it!

Comment: Well, sometimes we need another eyes to help us in the bug "hunting", it's ok :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `mainGraph[oldKey].Add(newValue);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply extending the list already in the Dictionary with key `oldKey` then `mainGraph[oldKey].Add(newValue);` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mainGraph[oldKey].Add(newValue);
```

- that's enough, no need to assign it to mainGraph[oldKey] (what could you expect)?
This call does not return anything - that's an action of adding a value to existing list. Your error says that you try to convert this action into some value.

You add value to existing list, this action modifies this list but it does not change the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your method

```
public void addLinkToGraph(int oldKey,int newValue)
{
    mainGraph[oldKey] = mainGraph[oldKey].Add(newValue);
}
```

Is that the result of `mainGraph[oldKey].Add(newValue)` is of type `void`. Setting the value of your dictionary at key `oldKey` to `void` doesn't make sense since the values of your dictionary must be of type `List<int>`. Try

```
public void addLinkToGraph(int oldKey,int newValue)
{
    mainGraph[oldKey].Add(newValue);
}
```

You may also want to consider if the dictionary has a key at the index you're  mutating; if not you will end up getting a `NullReferenceException`, which isn't so great.

Answer (score -1):

Before you can work with that List you must instantiate it. Sine in

```
List<int> dummyList = mainGraph[oldKey];
```

**dummyList** will be **null**; Keep in mind you must do so for each key in the Dictionary.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  `List<int> dummyList` **can** be instantiated by assigning an existing list (`mainGraph[oldKey]`) to it.